# Curious as to what the interpreter is doing here

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I was working through a decorator design pattern tutorial 
(credit to Jungwoo Ryoo)

I'm curious as to why I can swap the lines: `return decorator` 
and `print(hello_world())` with `return decorator()` and `print(hello_world)`

```
from functools import wraps

def make_blink(function):
    """Defines the decorator"""

    @wraps(function)
    # Define the inner function
    def decorator():

        # Grab the return value of the function being decorated
        ret = function()
        # Add new functionality to the function being decorated
        return "<blink>"+ ret + "<b/link>"
    return decorator #return decorator()#<THIS LINE HERE SWAPPED

# Apply the decorator here!
@make_blink
def hello_world():
    """Original function! """

    return "Hello, World!"

# Check the result of decorating
print(hello_world()) #print(hello_world) #<THIS LINE HERE SWAPPED
```

Wouldn't the interpreter be doing something different each time? I'm just looking for some insight to have a better understanding of what's going on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decorators are *just functions* really, and functions are just objects.

The lines

```
@make_blink
def hello_world():
    # ...
```

are essentially the same as

```
def hello_world():
    # ...
hello_world = make_blink(hello_world)
```

except the function object is never assigned to `hello_world` first (it's on the stack for to be passed to the decorator).

So **whatever you return from `make_blink()`** is assigned back to `hello_world`. That can be a function object, but it can also be something entirely different.

So when you use `return decorator`, you tell Python to set `hello_world` to the nested function object. When you use `return decorator()`, you tell Python to use the result of the `decorator()` function. Here, that's a string value. It's as if you did this:

```
def hello_world():
    """Original function! """
    return "Hello, World!"

hello_world = "<blink>" + hello_world() + "</blink>"
```

And that is fine for this specific example, because body of the `hello_world()` function only ever returns *the same string each time*.

But what if you changed the original `hello_world()` function body to return something different each time you called it? What if you had:

```
import random

@make_blink
def random_greeting():
    return 'Hello ' + random.choice('DonAr', 'Martijn Pieters', 'Guido van Rossum') + '!'
```

Now it makes a *big* difference what you return from the `make_blink()` call! For the top-level of a module, decorators are executed only *once*, when importing. If you used `return decorator()` you'd run `random.choice()` just once, and you have *fixed* the value of `random_greeting` to a single, static string result.

Generally speaking, decorators are expected to return a callable object again. That can be the original function (where the decorator just updates some kind of registration), a wrapper function (which does extra things before or after calling the original), or even something different entirely. But that's not set in stone anywhere, and the interpreter doesn't care either way.

Decorators are just *reusable things to use in your program*, a tool. If you have a specific use for a decorator that returns the result of the original function, then you are free to do so.

Comment: Thank you for adding the random_greeting() section. It illustrates the motive for when you would want to use return decorator() vs return decorator in such a clear way.